# How to navigate, or go to a folder in Google Drive with a Drive Add-On

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

I am pretty sure this is not possible, but it seems worthwhile asking.

**I want to use a Google Workspace Drive Add-On to help the user navigate, or go to a folder in their Drive. A folder that is currently not on the screen, but I know they have access to.**

The closest I have got to being able to do this is with button action and a callback

```
return CardService.newUniversalActionResponseBuilder()
    .setOpenLink(CardService.newOpenLink()
      .setUrl("https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/_Unique Google Drive Id Here_"))
    .build();
```

I also have my manifest set up correctly

```
 "urlFetchWhitelist": [
    "https://drive.google.com/drive/"
  ],
```

And this works as documented—it opens a new browser tab and takes the user to the target/desired folder.

But, I do not want to open a new browser tab.
**I want to either replace the current tab's URL. Or better still, have an API that tells Drive to go to the desired/target folder (on the screen) for the user.**
But there appears to be no such API or other hacks that make this possible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to know your motivations or what you want to achieve with the addon.
Anyways, I think the approach you're using has to be different.

As per `setUrl("https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/_Unique Google Drive Id Here_"))` you're fixing a static URL to open in your addon.

### Use the DriveApp

You can create a function to get the parentID of your current folder and dynamically set the URL to the new folder

```
function getParent() {
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById('file_ID')
  const folders = file.getParents()
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    let parent = folders.next()
    console.log(parent.getId())
  }
}
```

The [`getParents()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getParents()) method will return a [Folder Iterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder-iterator), so you need to match the one you're interested in